# What are the known conditions for a restriction on naive comprehension that enables a generalization of a property all so constructed sets meet?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Let $\mathcal Q$ be some qualification on formulas in the first order language of set theory (FOL($\in$)), *that is met by at least one formula*; Let $T$ be the first order set theory whose extra-logical axioms are the following *sole* axiom schema:

$\mathcal Q$-Comprehension schema: if $\phi(y)$ is a formula that meets qualification $\mathcal Q$, in which $x$ doesn't occur, and in which the symbol $y$ occurs free, and only free; then all closures of: $$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi(y))$$, are axioms.

Now suppose that $T$ is consistent, and that $\psi(x)$ is some formula in one free variable $x$, and $x$ only occur free in it, and suppose that theory $T$ proves that per the same conditions written above for $\mathcal Q$-Comprehension, all closures of following: $$\forall x [\forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi(y)) \to \psi(x)]$$, are theorems.

> Would it always follow that: $T + \forall x (\psi(x))$ is consistent?

The other question is:

> If not, then: are there known conditions that if qualifcation $\mathcal Q$ meets then $T + \forall x (\psi(x))$ would be consistent?

Comment: I'm confused, "$T$" seems to be doing double-duty here - as both an arbitrary theory (per the first half of the first sentence) and as the specific theory "$\mathcal{Q}$-comprehension." Can you clarify?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I've rephrased it. it should be clear by now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no. Suppose no formula meets qualification Q. Let () be x≠x.

The answer when  there is at least one formula  that meets qualification Q and the language does not have = as a primitive symbol, is still no. Suppose that the only formulas which meet qualification Q are 
(y∈y or not(y∈y)), and ∃u(tr(u)∧∀s(s∈y-->s∈u)∧∃s(s∈u∧empty(s))) where tr(u) is ∀w∀v(w∈u∧v∈w-->v∈u) and empty(w) is ∀x(not(x∈w)(that is y is contained in a transitive set which has an empty set as an element).
By Q-Comprehension,  there is an empty set. A universal set(guaranteed to exist by Q-Comprehension) is a transitive set which has an empty set as an element. Let () be ∃t(t∈x). Then for this Q, T is consistent(it holds in the 2 element set {a,b}
with the binary relation E, where E is defined by xEy iff y=b), 
∀[∀(∈↔())→()] is provable from T for all  meeting qualification Q, and +∀(()) is not consistent.

Comment: No this is wrong because T is consistent

Comment: The theory T with no non-logical axioms is consistent.  What is wrong?

Comment: when I said that $\mathcal Q$ is a *qualification* on the formulas of the language of theory $T$, this means that *some* formulas of the language must meet that qualification and others must not, otherwise why should one stipulate an empty schema, that doesn't make sense. Should I stipulate that there is at least one formula $\phi$ that meets qualification $\mathcal Q$ to make that clear?

Comment: Yes, because that changes the question.

Comment: changes made I'll edit it further, also notice that $=$ is not a primitive of the language here, and there are no identity axioms in the underlying logic. (although this of course doesn't affect your argument in case $\mathcal Q$ is not met.)

Comment: sometimes reality hits you hard

Comment: I wonder if the second question is answerable?